# how to register a receiver for capturing completed download?

Tags: android, receiver

I was checking some tutorial on how to notify the receiver when the DownloadManager has completed the download, they register receiver pragmatically like this

```
context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

while, I want to register the receiver in my `manifest.xml` instead of pragmatically, and I find out people are doing it like this

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".DownloadReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/download_icon" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

so whats the different between **android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED** and **DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE**? why they dont use `<action android:name="DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />` in the manifest?

Comment: Because `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` is a static string that *contains* the string `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`, see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) ("Constant Value").